# Set default value for datetime field in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

As per the rails_admin github documentation [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to-set-default-values), for my rails model I have set default value for paramters as:

```
rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :active do
      default_value true
    end
    field :loyalty_tier do
      default_value 1
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I try to set the value for a `datetime` attribute, it is not reflecting on the corresponding admin panel view as expected.

The following code snippet:

```
rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :effective_start do
      default_value DateTime.now
    end
    field :effective_end do
      default_value {DateTime.now + 99.years}
    end
  end
end
```

renders the view as:

[image]

which does not render the time part of DateTime, as visible. How exactly to set the default value for a datetime field in rails_admin ?

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644974/add-a-default-value-for-date-field-with-rails-admin

Comment: @corvuszero Thanks for the link.