# Add a default value for date field with rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Using `rails (4.2.10)` and `rails_admin (1.2.0)`
I am trying to addd a default date value to the `confirmed_at` field of the `User` Model.

It works on the edit view but not on the new view.

Here is my code :

```
config.model 'User' do
    list do
      [...]
    end

    show do
      [...]
    end

    edit do
      field :confirmed_at do
        default_value DateTime.now
      end
      exclude_fields 
            [...]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning a string instead and format it using the same format rails admin uses for datetime fields. I believe it to be

```
default_value I18n.l(DateTime.now, format: :long)
```

You can also try initializing the object with a default value on your model like this:

```
after_initialize do
  self.confirmed_at = DateTime.now
end
```

In an unrelated topic you should really be using Time.zone.now to avoid problems with time zones.

Comment: Works like a charm !

Comment: Great fix. Not easy to determine out of the blue